# エディタを使用し、正規表現で特定の文字列から特定の文字列までを指定し削除したい

Tags: 正規表現, エディタ

以下の「処理前」のテキストから、「処理後」のように `D-E-F` から `G-H-I` の前までを指定し削除を行いたいです。

### 処理前

```
A-B-C;hogehogehoge
D-E-F;fugafugafuga
      piyopiyopiyo
G-H-I;hogerahogera

A-B-C;HOGEHOGEHOGE
D-E-F;FUGAFUGAFUGA
      PIYOPIYOPIYO
G-H-I;HOGERAHOGERA
・
・
・
```

### 処理後

```
A-B-C;hogehogehoge
G-H-I;hogerahogera

A-B-C;HOGEHOGEHOGE
G-H-I;HOGERAHOGERA
・
・
・
```

[Yahoo!知恵袋の投稿](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13108148098)を参考に、`A-B-C`と`G-H-I`をグループ化し以下のように記述したのですが、「見つかりません」と表示されてしまいます。

```
検索する文字列：(A-B-C)[^(G-H-I)]*(G-H-I)
置換後の文字列：\r\nG-H-I
```

検索対象が文字単体の場合は動作するのですが、文字列を単純にグループ化するだけでは不十分なのでしょうか。

この場合、どのように記述するのが適切なのかご教授いただきたいです。

使用ソフトはMeryテキストエディタです。

Comment: 参考までに、テキストエディタではなく sed コマンドを使うのでしたら、`sed '/^D-E-F/,/^G-H-I/{/^G-H-I/b;d}' data.txt` となります。

Comment: @metropolis 様
頂いたsedコマンドを使って所望する結果を得ることができました。
本当にありがとうございました。
問題は解決済みですが、テキストエディタの置換機能で同様の処理ができないか気になったため、このままオープンにさせていただきます。

Comment: 正規表現を扱えるエディタは複数ありますが、今回の質問としてはひとまず「Mery を使って」が前提でしょうか？

Comment: @cubick 様　タグ付けおよび添削いただきありがとうございます。初心者なので非常に助かります。
私が普段使用しているテキストエディタがMeryというだけなので、正規表現が使えるエディタであればどんなものでも結構です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Mery テキストエディタ」を使ったことがないので御参考になりますが，Python の記述例を示します（処理前のテキスト: `temp.txt`）。
正規表現で最長一致ではなく最短一致させるには `*` の代わりに `*?` （`+?` `??` 等も同様）を使います。また，削除したい部分に改行も含まれるので `.` の代わりに `[\s\S]` （空白文字または空白文字以外の全ての文字）を使う必要があります。

```
import re

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    before = f.read()

after = re.sub(r'(A-B-C.*\n)[\s\S]*?(G-H-I)', r'\1\2', before)
print(after, end='')
```

```
A-B-C;hogehogehoge
G-H-I;hogerahogera

A-B-C;HOGEHOGEHOGE
G-H-I;HOGERAHOGERA
```

（追記）
Mery では `\S` が使えないようなので，代わりに `[^\s]` を使って `[\s\S]` を `(\s|[^\s])` と書けば置換できました。なお，かっこを増やしたので置換後も `\1\3` とする必要があります。

[image: 置換の設定画面]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。参考になりました。頂いた情報で色々試してみましたが、やはり当該の処理をする場合、テキストエディタの機能のみでは不十分のような気がしてきました。

Answer (score 1):

> 正規表現が使えるエディタであればどんなものでも

**VS Codeでの場合:**

VS Codeによる 複数行にまたがる検索では `\n`を明示的に指定する必要があるようです
なので, `D-E-F` から `G-H-I` の前までは

検索文字列: `^D-E-F(.*\n)*?(?=G-H-I)`

※
<del>後読みアサーション指定のつもりが有効にならず, 先読みアサーションでヒットした</del>
(置換文字列を `G-H-I` にするのなら, 先読みアサーションにする必要はない)